# std::launch::async runs sequentially when compiled as R-package

Tags: c++, multithreading, rcpp, r-package, stdasync

I have a problem with the behavior of std::launch::async

I have two cases where I use std::launch::async:

Case 1:

```
    const AnotherClass AnyClass::train(args) const{

        // first do some stuff

        std::vector<uint> thread_ranges;
        split_sequence(thread_ranges, 0, num_groups - 1, options.get_num_threads());
        std::vector<std::future<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AnotherClass> > > > futures;
        futures.reserve(thread_ranges.size());

        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tree> > results;
        results.reserve(num_trees);

        for (uint i = 0; i < thread_ranges.size() - 1; ++i) {
            futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async,
                                         &ForestTrainer::AnotherClassFunction,
                                         this,
                                         someArgs));
        }

        for (auto& future : futures) {
            std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AnotherClass> > thread_results = future.get();
            results.insert(results.end(), thread_results.begin(), thread_results.end());
        }

        // then do some other stuff
    }

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tree> > ForestTrainer::train_batch(someArgs
    {
        // do a lot of stuff
    }
```

And Case 2:

```
    std::tuple<T1, T2> innerFunction(manyArgs){
        // do a lot of stuff
        return std::make_tuple(someThing, otherThing);
    }

    Eigen::MatrixXd outerFunction(args){
        // do some stuff
        std::vector<T1> results_1;
        std::vector<T2> results_2;

        for(uint i =0; i<num_trees;i=i+num_threads){
    
            std::vector<std::future<std::tuple<T1,T2> > > futures = std::vector<std::future<std::tuple<T1,T2> > >(threads_to_run);
            for(uint j=0;j<num_threads; j++){
                futures[j]=std::async(std::launch::async,
                                      &innerFunction,
                                      trees.at(i+j),
                                      otherArgs);
            }

            for (auto& future : futures) {
                T1 get_1;
                T2 get_2;
                std::tie(get_1, get_2)=future.get();
                if(get_2.empty()){
                    results_1.insert(results_1.end(), get_1.begin(), get_1.end());
                } else {
                    results_2.insert(results_2.end(), get_2.begin(), get_2.end());
                }
            }
            // do some stuff
        }
        // do some stuff
   }
```

When I debug and run the code in Ecplise C++, everything works fine and I get 100% CPU usage.

When I compile the Code as part of an R-package using Rcpp, only in Case 1, I get full CPU usage, but in Case 2, the threads run sequentially with only 1/nThreads CPU usage.

I tried to simplify the code as much as possible here but still keep the important features. If something is missing that could be helpful, let me know.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Could `num_threads` be equal to 1 in some configurations in case #2?

Comment: Is it based on `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` or something else?

Comment: Did you initialize num_threads to supported hardware concurrency? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency

Comment: Same thinking here--maybe look into `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT` and other environment variables governing this,  You could also have forgotten to set `-fopenmp` as compiler and linker flags for the R package, it is hard says as you did not supply a [minimally complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: num_threads is fine. I can check it at run time and it is set accordingly. I also see that the supposed number of threads is created when I check the task manager. 
What really puzzles me is that it runs as expected as stand-alone in eclipse, but when I compile and run it as part of an R-package, only one case is run in parallel and for the other, the threads seem to run sequentionally.